# Adjacency Matrix to Edge List in Haskell

Tags: list, haskell, graph, multidimensional-array, adjacency-matrix

I have a 1d list of teams of a tournament and a 2d "opponent matrix".

I simply want to extract a list of opponents for each team.

I'm just learning Haskell and want to know, if anybody could think of a more elegant solution for the already working code below. ... Maybe a list comprehension ? ...

**Code:**

```
findOp :: (Eq a, Num a) => [b] -> [a] -> [b]
findOp (x:xs) (y:ys) | y == 1 = [x] ++ findOp xs ys
                     | otherwise = findOp xs ys

findOp [] [] = []

tab = [[0,1,0,1],
       [1,0,1,0],
       [0,1,0,1],
       [1,0,1,0]]

teams = ["team a",
         "team b",
         "team c",
         "team d" ]

main :: IO ()
main = do
       let games = map (\x -> (fst x, findOp teams $ snd x)) $ zip teams tab
       putStrLn $ show games
```

**Result:**

```
[("team a",["team b","team d"]),("team b",["team a","team c"]),("team c",["team b","team d"]),("team d",["team a","team c"])]
```

Comment: ... and maybe someone finds a better title for the question!

Comment: your "arrays" are *lists* and can you please give a simple example of what you want to do here? What is a *draw* matrix? And how is this connected to the teams and opponents?

Comment: It's a graph problem, and one simple enough that it's not completely silly to use lists - there's no random accessing, for instance.

Comment: This is probably better-suited to the code review stack exchange, though.

Comment: @Carl: didn't know cr stack so far. ... good idea!

Comment: @CarstenKönig: "draw matrix" ... it's a matrix of opponents of a tournament. Who plays against who.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Anyway, presuming this will get migrated soon, here's an answer:

```
tab = [[0,1,0,1],
       [1,0,1,0],
       [0,1,0,1],
       [1,0,1,0]]

teams = ["team a",
         "team b",
         "team c",
         "team d" ]

main = do
    let matches = zip teams . map (map fst . filter ((== 1) . snd) . zip teams) $ tab
    print matches
```

The key insight is starting with `map (zip teams) tab`. This gives you team names inside the matrix, along with the values.  From there, the rest is simple data manipulation - and a manual fusion of the three operations mapped over each inner list.

By the way - this is really a specific example of the general problem of converting an adjacency matrix to an edge list.  It's one of the simplest and most fundamental operations when working with graph representations in software.

Comment: Thx... May you edit the title to something meaningful? I see you are familiar with that kind of problems.